# Python regex: Matching bracket/parenthesis pairs

Tags: python, regex

I want to catch bracket/parenthesis pairs that are next to each other and get hold of the words inside them. In the following text I want to catch `[oh](so)` and `[bad](things)`.

```
[oh](so)funny
[all]the[bad](things)
```

If I use the regex `r'\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)'` it will catch `[oh](so)` and `[all]the[bad](things)`, which is not what I want.

What's a good regex to solve this?

Comment: You could also loop over your pairs of delimiters. Also your question is similar to this one for anyone interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `.*?`.

Instead use `[^\]]+` and `[^\)]+`

In other words:

`r'\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)'`

Comment: It does the trick! But it would still fail at `[some[good](text)]`. Here I want to catch `[good](text)` only. Any idea how to deal with this situation as well?

Comment: That wasn't part of your question.  If you need more sophisticated  tag matching, I would recommend using a parsing module of some sort.  That said, `\[([^\]\[]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)` will correctly match the example in your comment.

Comment: @thameera: To expand on what Lone Shepherd said, regular expressions *can't* deal with nested brackets.  You can prove that the language consisting only of balanced parentheses is non-regular, *i.e.* that it cannot be matched by any regular expression.  Python regexen are more powerful than formal regular expressions (as are most modern implementations, thanks to backreferences), but I don't think they have the necessary power to recognize the even simpler language consisting of all strings of the form `a...ab...b` with an equal number of `a`s and `b`s.

Comment: @AntalS-Z: while you're correct about python stock `re`, more advanced regex engines (pyhon regex, pcre, net etc) can match nested brackets and `a^n b^n` by means of recursive groups, like `(?R)`.